# How can you trace an object back to the DLL that provides it?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

The Object browser doesn't tell where the object came from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The object browser will tell you the providing DLL if you click on the root node of the tree where the object is located.  The name will appear in the bottom right hand part of the screen.

For example

[image]

Provides the following location

> Assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor
>       C:\Users\JaredP\VsVim\References\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.dll

Comment: @James thanks.  Very, very close now.  I need to hit rep cap + 2 accepted answers to make it today (224 shy at EOD yesterday).  Already have 2 accepted and 60 rep so right on track.